# jquery branching in a form

Tags: jquery

A few months ago I thought I would "have a go" at creating a sign up form with no experience at all with jquery or java except copying and pasting code that works ok into my web pages.
I made a pretty fancy form up but it wont work with validation.
I have several branches in the form i.e. 2 radio buttons labelled business and private. If you click business it asks one set of questions and if you click private another set. 
I am having difficulty locating anything that explains how I "switch off" the unused questions or how to do a branch that is a separate pathway.
If someone could direct me to a tutorial that gives me a clue that would be great or any other help would be appreciated.
Here is the code I have so far.

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Plans</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Join Now</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
//1
    {
                $('.newp').hide();                  //hide all div 
                $('.tranp').hide();
                $('.bushom').hide();
                $('.diffadd').hide();
                $('.tac').hide();
                $('.conadd').hide();
                $('.subbut').hide();
                $('#newp').click(function()
                {
                        $('.tranp').slideUp('slow');        //where there is an alternate use slide
                        $('.newp').slideDown('slow');
            $('.bushom').show('slow');      //if no alternate use show. if it should not be shown in another sequence use hide
                });
                $('#tranp').click(function()
                {
                        $('.newp').slideUp('slow');
                        $('.tranp').slideDown('slow');
                        $('.bushom').show('slow');
                });     
//2
                $('.busu').hide();
                $('.homeu').hide();
                $('.tac').hide();
                $('.conadd').hide();
                $('.subbut').hide();
                $('#busu').click(function()
                {
        //        $('.newp').hide();
        //        $('.tranp').hide();
                        $('.homeu').slideUp('slow');
                        $('.busu').slideDown('slow');
            $('.diffadd').show('slow');
                });
                $('#homeu').click(function()
                {
        //        $('.newp').hide();                //an example of how we can hide completed pages so there is not to much on the screen
        //        $('.tranp').hide();
                        $('.busu').slideUp('slow');
                        $('.homeu').slideDown('slow');
            $('.diffadd').show('slow');
                });     
//3
                $('.addsame').hide();
                $('.adddif').hide();
                $('.conadd').hide();
                $('.tac').hide();
                $('.subbut').hide();
                $('#addsame').click(function()
                {
                        $('.conadd').hide('slow');          //here is an example where a page has to hide in one sequence but be shown in another
                        $('.tac').show('slow');
                });
                $('#adddif').click(function()
                {
                        $('.conadd').show('slow');
                        $('.tac').show('slow');
                });     

                $('.addsame').hide();
                $('.adddif').hide();
                $('.conadd').hide();
                $('.tac').hide();
                $('.agree').hide();
                $('.subbut').hide();
                $('#agree').click(function()
        {
                        $('.subbut').show('slow');
                });

/*
       $("#signupForm").validate({
                rules: {
                        stnantr: "required",
                        subtr: "required",
                        citytr: "required",
                        stnannw: "required",
                        suburbnw: "required",
                        citynw: "required"

newtran:
{
    required: function(){
        if($("select[name=newtran]").val() == 1){
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

        $("#bushom").validate({
        if(newtran=='trans') {
                rules: {
            stnantr: "required",
            subtr: "required",
            citytr: "required"
                        }
                }
        else {
                rules: {
                        stnannw: "required",
                        suburbnw: "required",
                        citynw: "required"
                        }       

                },
                messages: {
            stnantr: "required",
                        subtr: "required",
                        citytr: "required",
            stnannw: "required",
                        suburbnw: "required",
                        citynw: "required"
                }
        });

*/
    });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #content { 
    width: 600px; 
    margin: 1px auto; 
    padding: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 10px solid #666699;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    }
    h2 { 
        color: #666;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px; 
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .option {
    color: #555; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    margin-right: 20px; 
    }
    .detail {       
    width: 500px;  
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
    color: #333; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    }
    a { 
    color: #3399CC; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    }
    a:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    }
    label { 
        color: #666;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    }
    label.error {
        float: none;
        color: red;
        padding-left: .5em;
        vertical-align: top;
    }   

        legend {
        color: #666;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;

    font-size: 10px; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
        }
    .input { 
    color: #666; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    border: 1px solid #336666;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    input.button {
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 10px; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

</style>

<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2462.0" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
<BODY text=#666666 vLink=#800080 link=#0000FF bgColor=#006699 topMargin=0 marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div style="background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;">
<TABLE bgColor=#ffffff cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=700 border=0 ALIGN="center">
      <TR> 
    <!--MAIN AD AREA--> 
    <TD vAlign=top align=top width=370 height="293"> 
        <div align="top"></div>

        <p align="top">
    <style='mso-bidi-font-weight:bold'><span style='font-size:18pt;font-family:Arial;mso-bidi-font-family:"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";color:blue'>Join Now
        <o:p></o:p></span></p>

        <div align="top"></div>
<div id="content">
    <form id="signupForm" method="POST" action="processform.php">
        <div>
             <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 1</legend><br />
                <div class="detail">Do you want to TRANSFER an EXISTING phone number <br />OR<br />
        Do you want to INSTALL a NEW Service</div><br />
                <input type="radio" name="newtran" value="tranp" id="tranp" /> <span class="option"> Transfer EXISTING Service</span>
        <input type="radio" name="newtran" value="newp" id="newp" /><span class="option"> Install a NEW Service</span>
        <br /><br />
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="tranp"><br />
            <fieldset>
                        <legend>TRANSFER an EXISTING Service</legend><br />
                        <label for="tranphtr">Existing Phone Number</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="tranphtr" class="input" id="tranphtr"/><br />
                        <label for="cprovtr">Current Provider</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="cprovtr" class="input" id="cprovtr"/><br />
                        <label for="anumtr">Account Number</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="anumtr" class="input" id="anumtr"/><br />
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <fieldset>
                        <legend>ADDRESS of EXISTING Service</legend><br />
                        <label for="stnantr">Street Number and Name</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="stnantr" class="input" id="stnantr"/><br />
                        <label for="suburbtr">Suburb</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="suburbtr" class="input" id="suburbtr"/><br />
                        <label for="citytr">City</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="citytr" class="input" id="citytr" /><br />
                        <label for="pcodetr">Post Code</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="pcodetr" class="input" id="pcodetr"/><br />
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="newp"><br />
                            <fieldset>
            <legend>Customer Service Agreement</legend><br />
            <div class="detail">
            When ordering a NEW phone service there is a right to recourse if the installation is delayed for any reason under the telecommunications act 
            called the CUSTOMER SERVICE AGREEMENT.<br /><br />
            If you require this protection against delays in connecting your new service please check the box labelled REQUIRE.<br /> <br />
            If you decide to waive your protection under the act please check the box labelled WAIVE.<br /> <br />
            There is a substantial difference in the price if you WAIVE your rights under the telecommunications act.<br /><br />
            It will take the same time to install the phone if you are covered or waive your rights the difference is you have a right to 
            recourse if there is an unforseen delay.</div><br /><br />
            <h2>WAIVE</h2>
                    <input type="radio" name="waivereq" value="waive" id="wav" /> <span class="option">
            I WAIVE the CUSTOMER SERVICE AGREEMENT and will pay an installation fee of $70</span><br /><br />
            <h2>REQUIRE</h2>
                    <input type="radio" name="waivereq" value="require" id="req" /><span class="option">
            I REQUIRE the CUSTOMER SERVICE AGREEMENT and will pay an installation fee of $200</span>
                            </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Enter the ADDRESS where the NEW phone service is LOCATED</legend><br />
                        <label>Street Number and Name</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="stnannw" class="input" id="stnannw"/><br />
                        <label>Suburb</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="suburbnw" class="input" id="suburbnw"/><br />
                        <label>City</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="citynw" class="input" id="citynw" /><br />
                        <label>Post Code</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="pcodenw" class="input" id="pcodenw"/><br />
                    </fieldset>
        </div>

            <br />
        <div class="bushom">
            <fieldset>
                        <legend>Question 2</legend><br />
            <div class="detail">Is this Phone Service for Home or Business Use <br /></div>
                    <input type="radio" name="hombus" value="homeuse" id="homeu" /> <span class="option">For Home Use</span>
            <input type="radio" name="hombus" value="bususe" id="busu" /><span class="option">For Business Use</span>
            <br />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
                <div class="homeu"><br />
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>HOME Use</legend><br />
                    <label for="firstnamehm">Firstname:</label><br />
                                <input type="text" id="firstnamehm" class="input" name="firstnamehm" /> *<br />
                                <label for="lastnamehm">Lastname:</label><br />
                                <input type="text" id="lastnamehm" class="input" name="lastnamehm" /> *<br />
                                <label for="emailhm">Email:</label><br />
                                <input type="text" id="emailhm" class="input" name="emailhm" /><br />
                                <label for="phonehm">Contact Phone:</label><br />
                                <input type="text" id="phonehm" class="input" name="phonehm" /> *<br />     
                            </fieldset>
                </div>
                        <div class="busu"><br />
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <legend>BUSINESS Use</legend><br />
                        <div class="detail">
                        <fieldset>1. For Business use the cost of the service is $6 extra per month
                        <br />This fee is for a standard entry in Yellow Pages<br /><br />
                        2. The contact person should be the person responsible for making decisions and billing for this service.<br />
                        Usually the proprietor or a director of the business<br /> 
                        </fieldset>
                        <div><br />
                                        <label for="busnamebs">Business Name:</label><br />
                                        <input type="text" id="busnamebs" class="input" name="busnamebs" /> *<br />
                                        <label for="abnnbs">ABN:</label><br />
                                        <input type="text" id="abnnbs" class="input" name="abnnbs" /> *<br />
                                        <label for="firstnamebs">Firstname:</label><br />
                                        <input type="text" id="firstnamebs" class="input" name="firstnamebs" /> *<br />
                                        <label for="lastnamebs">Lastname:</label><br />
                                        <input type="text" id="lastnamebs" class="input" name="lastnamebs" /> *<br />
                                        <label for="emailbs">Email:</label><br />
                                        <input type="text" id="emailbs" class="input" name="emailbs" /><br />
                                        <label for="phonebs">Contact Phone:</label><br />
                                        <input type="text" id="phonebs" class="input" name="phonebs" /> *<br />
                                    </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                <div class="diffadd">
                    <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Address</legend><br />
                     <div class="detail">
                                           <fieldset>Is the SERVICE ADDRESS (above) the same as your CONTACT ADDRESS<br />
                                           </fieldset>
                                            <div><br />
                <input type="radio" name="adiff" value="addsame" id="addsame" /> <span class="option">YES</span>
                <input type="radio" name="adiff" value="adddif" id="adddif" /><span class="option">NO</span>
                <br />
               </fieldset>
           </div>
        <div class="conadd"><br />
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Contact Address</legend><br />
                        <label>Street Number and Name</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="constreetnan" class="input" id="constreetnan"/><br />
                        <label>Suburb</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="consuburb" class="input" id="consuburb"/><br />
                        <label>City</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="concity" class="input" id="concity" /><br />
                        <label>Post Code</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="conpcode" class="input" id="conpcode"/><br />
                    </fieldset>
        </div>

    <div class="tac"><br />
        <div class="detail">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Customer Authority.</legend><br /><br />
            <textarea rows="15" cols="65" readonly>
Customer Authority.
AN AUTHORITY TO SUPPLY A NEW TELEPHONE SERVICE OR TRANSFER AN EXISTING SERVICE.

        </textarea><br /><br />
        <h2><input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree" id="agree">I agree to the Terms & Conditions.</h2><br /><br />
        </fieldset>
                </div>
        </div>
          <div class="subbut"><br />
                        <fieldset>
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </fieldset>
          </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

~end snip